# Bootstrap progress bar missing stripes in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
        <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using the sample straight from the docs I don't see any stripes on the progress bar. How do I get them to display?

Using MVC 5 and Bootstrap v3.2.0

[image]

Comment: [**This bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/G8UI48BHUG) shows the progress bar just fine. Are you using ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: Yes I realize it works in bootply and jsfiddle, it just isn't working in my MVC project. I'm pretty stumped. Tested the page in latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, IE 11. @simple sandman Yes ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: What does Firebug or a developer viewer say about the `progress-bar-striped` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across the some problem just now, and it seems as if moving the two classes that make the progress bar animate (`progress-striped` and `active`) from the `progress-bar` to the parent element `progress` works perfectly.

As you can see from the working example below, both will work perfectly. Although, if rendered with MVC, only the bottom one will work.

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://www.bootply.com/tCQgOIKVoK)** (Bottom one is the one that will work for you)

**Working HTML:**

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
        <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tested in latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, IE 11 and they are all the same, missing stripes. When I use inspect element the above is the exact output.

Comment: @JonD - Came across the same problem just now. Found a solution, check it out.

Comment: HA! What the heck. And progress-striped instead of progress-bar-striped. Thank you very much. I would up-vote but not enough rep yet looks like.

Comment: @TechnoCore - Yeah, very strange haha. Oh well, somehow I figured it out.